# WPF: Icon as Path with editable Dependency Properties

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a set of simple geometries in WPF (check mark, arrows, etc.)  I have these defined by `Path` which is nice because they are actually rendered rather than being rasterized.

The trouble I have is that I want to be able to change some of the properties of the Path (the Fill in particular) and I'm struggle as to how to implement.  Do I use Styles, do I have something that contains it like UserControl?  I'll have a handful of these so I don't want to have a bunch of duplicate controls.

I can't actually have a type that derives from Path because the class is sealed.  That was where I went first.

Comment: See if the following link works for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Did you consider to derive from [Shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.aspx) instead of Path (and implement the [DefiningGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.defininggeometry.aspx) property)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what finally worked was I created a control that derived from ViewBox.  On the ViewBox I added a "FillBrush" dependency property of type `Brush`.

I then just stamp out instances of this control and fill it with Path objects that have the correct Data and bind their Fill property to the FillBrush dependency property.